# Detecting lines in an image using OpenCV with Python

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, pattern-recognition, houghlines

[Updated The Question at the End]
I'm trying to detect a design pattern of simple geometrical shapes in a 640x480 image. I have divided the image in 32x32 blocks and checking in which block each shape's center lies.

Based on this calculation I created a numpy matrix of (160x120) zeros (float32) with

`col=640/4
row=480/4`

Each time a shape is found, the center is calculated and check in which block it is found. The corresponding item along with its 8 neighbors in 160x120 numpy array are set to **1**. In the end the 160x120 numpy array is represented as a grayscale image with black background and white pixels representing the blocks of detected shapes.

As shown in the image below. 
[image: The image in top left corner represents the 160x120 numpy array.]

The image in top left corner represents the 160x120 numpy array. No issue so far.

As you can see the newly generated image has a white line on black foreground. I want to find the rho,theta,x0,y0,x1,y1 for this line. So I decided to use HoughLines transformation for this.

For is as followed:

```
edges = cv2.Canny(np.uint8(g_quadrants), 50, 150, apertureSize=3)
lines = cv2.HoughLines(edges, 1, np.pi / 180, 200)
print lines
```

Here `g_quadrants` is the 160x120 matrix representing a gray scale image but output of `cv2.HoughLines` does not contain anything but `None`.

Please help me with this.

**Update:**

[image: The real scenario]

The small window with a black and white (np.float32 consider GrayScale) image displaying a white is what I get actually when I

- Divide the 640x480 in 32x32 blocks
- Find the triangles in the image
- Create a 32x32 matrix to map the results for each block
- Update the corresponding matrix element by **1** if a triangle is found in a block

**Zoomed View:**

[image: Zoomed View of 32x32 np.float32 Image]

You can see there are white pixels forming a straight line. The may be some unwanted detected. I need to eliminate unwanted lone pixels and reconstructing a continuous straight line. That may be achieved by dilating then eroding the image. I need the find x0,y0, x1,y1, rho, theta of this line.

Their may be more than one lines. In that case I need to find top 2 lines with respect to length.

Comment: Don't you already have a good line in the results? You don't need hough transform to solve this. in fact you can just use simple linear regression to obtain the offset and slope represeting the line as y=mx+b(you can use opencv fitline to get m and b)

Comment: I may have many other points other than those forming a line. E.g. a triangle detected far away from the main line. Or I may have multiple lines in different orientations.

Comment: @Silencer I need to apply```cv2.HoughLines``` on the small image at top left. The image is actually a matrix of 160x120 ```float32``` elements containing **0** and **1** values. So can be considered as a grayscale image. I need to find all the lines appearing in that image. I applied Canny Edge detection followed by HoughLines but resultant list of Lines is empty.

Comment: `HoughLines` [requires](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/imgproc/doc/feature_detection.html#houghlines) `uint8` source images, you can't use a `float` image (it's best to just use `uint8` for masks anyways). Further, you'll probably get hundreds of lines through those points from `HoughLines`, you'd have to tweak all the parameters just so to get a single line here (and still wouldn't get a good line). Instead it would probably be easiest to detect contours and find the angle and size of the `minAreaRect()` around the white blobs. What do you actually need the angle for?

Comment: I didn't even see the part about the edges. Look at the `edges` image you're generating. Your code is looking for lines in *that* image, not the original image---meaning you'll just be looking for lines which are the outline of the blocky line-shape, and you'll not find any with such a high score (200).

Comment: Ah i did not receive notifications on this since I did not post as answer, anyway. Please try skeletonization(and maybe a single dilate step after it) and perform hough transform after that. I believe you are unable to detect the line because it's too thick.

Comment: considering thin lines....my image in now 15x20 and  a single pixel wide lines appears in it. still no results.